# spfx pnp 404 when getting myProperties

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core, 404

I try to fetch my properties using the `sp.profiles.myProperties.get()` from @pnp/sp.

It works on a hosted workbench but when I deployed the package and run it on Sharepoint site page I'm getting `Error making HttpClient request in queryable [404] Not Found`

Why is that so and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the inital setup which is necessary to determine the request URLs in SPFx context.

In your webpart.ts file, add the below piece of code:

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

// ...

protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

  return super.onInit().then(_ => {

    // other init code may be present

    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context
    });
  });
}

// ...
```

Reference - [PnPJS getting started](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/#getting-started-with-sharepoint-framework)